# Interpolating variables when passing arguments to a view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to render a bunch of dynamic `<select>` boxes, supplied by a model. The user is supposed to fill these out, after which the data is saved. Currently I'm looping over the `availableParameters` object and rendering an `Ember.Select` view for each of the pairs in the object. This works alright. However, I'm having trouble setting up the `valueBinding` in such a way that I can retrieve the values in the controller, because I can't seem to interpolate the `label` variable in the passed argument to the view.

```
{{#each availableParameters}}
    {{label}}
    {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding="values"
        valueBinding="controller.param.[label]"
    }}
{{/each}}
```

The `availableParameters` object looks like this:

```
[
    {
        label: "label1",
        values: [
           "value1",
           "value2",
           "value3"
        ]
    },
    ...
 ]
```

Is there a way to dynamically set the value of the `valueBinding` to `controller.param.[label1]` (using the array of objects above) or is there a better way of achieving what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to do:

```
selectedValue: function() {
  this.get('values')[this.get('label')]
}.property('values.[]', 'label')
```

This property can be on the itemController for the `{{#each}}` helper if you need it to be (an itemController is a good way to approach this problem)